# what's the native utf encoding for CFString in OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-text

This should be easy to find out but I can't seem to find it anywhere - so please excuse if it's a no brainer. What's the native UTF storage used in a CFString, UTF-16, UTF-8 etc.

Why I'm asking is I'm interfacing to some lua code and lua can handle UTF-8 strings but if I convert them to CFSTring, then there'll be a performance penalty if it uses UTF-16 internally?

I had a look at the CFStringGetSystemEncoding and it returns mac roman - which doesn't seem to be correct.

locale returns

LANG="en_AU.UTF-8"...

which indicates it's utf-8 but then the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/Articles/UnicodeBasis.html) seem to indicate it's 16 bit?

tia

Comment: Also check out the source code provided by Apple: https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1153.18/CFString.h.auto.html Though it says same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is short chapter “[String storage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/Articles/StringStorage.html)” in the docs saying that it can have various encodings internally:

> Although conceptually CFString objects store strings as arrays of Unicode characters, in practice they often store them more efficiently. The memory a CFString object requires to represent a string could often be less than that required by a simple UniChar array.

The last paragraph suggests a solution for those who are concerned about extra conversions:

> You can get further control over the backing store of a string with the CFStringCreateMutableWithExternalCharactersNoCopy function. This function creates a reference to a mutable CFString object but allows you to retain full ownership of the Unicode buffer holding the object’s characters; the object itself points to the buffer as its backing store.

Comment: many thanks, I must have looked in the docs a 100 times and didn't see that chapter